# Rewriterule to handle mix of variables and undeclared variables in URLs

Tags: .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to write a rewrite rule for my `.htaccess` - it should ideally allow you to search through a database for items matching some of the criteria specified - there are eleven variables but searches will commonly only use three or four at a time (sometimes all eleven though). As an example the URL could be ;

```
?one=ONE&two=&three=&four=&five=&six=SIX
```

but I'd like to be able to use `/ONE/SIX` as the results page. It would also need to handle `/ONE/TWO/SIX, /ONE/FOUR/FIVE/SIX` and each of the other permutations as well.

Is this possible?

My experience of rewriterules is very limited and I'm not sure I'm even wording the question correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With a URL path like `/ONE/FOUR/FIVE/SIX`, how would you want to decide that these parameters are to be number 1, 4, 5 and 6 – and not any other possible combination …?

Comment: The first variable 'one' would only ever be (red|blue|green|orange), 'two' would only be (big|small), is this beyond the ability of a rewriterule?

Comment: No, regular expressions can express or-conditions quite easily … actually, with `(foo|bar)` you already have the syntax right there. Now you would only have to make those and the following slash optional.

Comment: Thanks, I have the following and it works perfectly! `search/(red|blue)?/?(big|small)?/?$ search.php?col=$1&size=$2 [NC,L]`